# usb_cam on imac isight: "No space left on device"

Tags: ros, usb-cam, virtualbox, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fresh install of diamondback and Lucid in VirtualBox on my mac, I installed usb_cam (bosch-drivers), but get the following error when running:

VIDIOC_STREAMON error 28, No space left on device

I get a similar error when I try to run guvcview.

Any advice on resolving this issue?  Is it a virtual machine problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10036/usb_cam-on-imac-isight:-%22no-space-left-on-device%22/) by [jrieffel](https://answers.ros.org/users/432/jrieffel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2011-05-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-05-26**:
How much space is on your virtual machine.  Try running 'df -h' in your console, and posting the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What else is attached and running on your USB bus? This error typically means you have exceeded the bus capacity (for instance I frequently had this issue when attempting to access two high resolution webcam images when playing with stereo vision).

-Fergs

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2